# Python list not work like list

Tags: python, arrays, list, indexing, printing

```
openFile = open('user.txt', 'r')
data =[]
data = openFile.read())
print((data[0])
```

This is my user.txt file data:

> [["admin", "123", "2017-May-21 01:43:37"], ["nimal", "456", "2017-Apr-10 21:24:48"], ["kamal", "8745", "2017-Apr-15 21:25:46"]]

it is 2D list. but when read and get this data i cant print arrays using index.

Output:

```
[
```

I need this output:

```
['admin', '123', '2017-May-21 01:43:37']
```

Comment: what about `print(data)`. also there are parenthesis mismatch in your code. `data` represents the whole string and `data[0]` represents the first character which in your case is `[`

Comment: When you read from file then this will be a string.so if print 0th index then it will be '[' this only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your data is a [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) encoded string. you can decode it to a python list like this:

```
import json

strg = '''[["admin", "123", "2017-May-21 01:43:37"], ["nimal", "456", "2017-Apr-10 21:24:48"], ["kamal", "8745", "2017-Apr-15 21:25:46"]]'''

data = json.loads(strg)

print(data[0])
# ['admin', '123', '2017-May-21 01:43:37']
```

or you can read directly from the file:

```
with open('user.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
print(data[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you assign data to an empty list:

```
data =[]
```

But then you assign data to the text contents of a file:

```
data = openFile.read())
```

... and it's no longer a list.  It seems like you're expecting `data` to somehow magically remember that it was previously a list and interpret its new content according to that type, but it doesn't do that.

The contents of `user.txt` *look like* a 2D list, but it's just text.  But because the text looks *exactly* like a 2D list, you can use the `json` module to do what you want:

```
import json
openFile = open('user.txt', 'r')
data = json.load(openFile)
print (data[0])
```

Comment: I need this output:

['admin', '123', '2017-May-21 01:43:37']